# Template literal not resolving to type key

Tags: typescript

I have the following object snippet below that represent a SOAP message and I want to store the namespace into a const variable in order to avoid hardcoding it in multiple places.

```
const MY_NAMESPACE_VARIABLE = 'purch';
const ITEM_KEY = `${MY_NAMESPACE_VARIABLE}:itemList` as const;

record: {
  attributes: {
   [`xmlns:${MY_NAMESPACE_VARIABLE}`]: 'urn:example.com',
  },
  ...,
  ...,
  [ITEM_KEY]: itemList.flat(),
}
```

I also declared a type for the above:

```
export type MyObject = {
  record: {
    attributes: Record<string, string>;
    'purch:itemList': any[];
  };
};
```

Without const assertion on the ITEM_KEY, the purch:itemList key is not resolved by Typescript at compilation. However, const asserting the template literal as seen in the ITEM_KEY constant gives me the following error: `A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.`

What can be done to resolve this error given the type or is there an alternative way to reference a template literal in the key of an object?

Comment: what do you mean with "the purch:itemList key is not resolved by Typescript at compilation". There is no error when using at as shown above https://tsplay.dev/NnKjem

Comment: @TobiasS. I do get an error about the purch:itemList property is missing  in type '{ attributes: { [x: string]: string; 'xmlns:common': string; 'xmlns:core': string; 'xsi:type': string; }; }' but required in type '{ attributes: Record<string, string>; 'purch:itemList': any[]; }'.

Comment: what do I have to do to reproduce the error?

Comment: @TobiasS. You will reproduce this error if you change this line to const ITEM_KEY = `${MY_NAMESPACE_VARIABLE}:itemList`;

Comment: Ok, but why don't you keep the `as const` when declaring `ITEM_KEY`?

Comment: As this is giving me a different error when executing the script that call its/ the unit test i have written for it (```A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.```)